# Taking single values of array components of derived type with type procedure

Tags: fortran, gfortran

My IDE is Code::Blocks 17.2 with compiler GFortran 6.3.1

The code is:

```
MODULE CLASS_BRANCHES

IMPLICIT NONE

  TYPE , PUBLIC :: TS_SHIR

    PRIVATE

      COMPLEX , ALLOCATABLE :: Y_BRA (:)

    CONTAINS

      PROCEDURE , PUBLIC :: CALCULATION_TS_SHIR => CALCULATION_DATA_TS_SHIR
!      PROCEDURE , PUBLIC :: TAKE_Y_BRA => TAKE_DATA_Y_BRA

  END TYPE TS_SHIR

  PRIVATE :: CALCULATION_DATA_TS_SHIR
!  PRIVATE :: TAKE_DATA_Y_BRA

CONTAINS

SUBROUTINE CALCULATION_DATA_TS_SHIR( THIS , N_BRA )

  IMPLICIT NONE

  CLASS ( TS_SHIR ) , INTENT( INOUT ) :: THIS
  INTEGER , INTENT ( IN ) :: N_BRA
  INTEGER :: I , ALLOC_ERR

  IF ( .NOT. ALLOCATED ( THIS%Y_BRA ) ) ALLOCATE ( THIS%Y_BRA ( N_BRA ) , STAT = ALLOC_ERR )

  IF ( ALLOC_ERR .NE. 0 ) STOP ("MEMORY ALLOCATION PROBLEM - THIS%Y_BRA!")

  DO I = 1 , N_BRA

     THIS%Y_BRA(I) = CMPLX ( 11 + I , 12 + I )

  END DO

RETURN
END SUBROUTINE CALCULATION_DATA_TS_SHIR

!FUNCTION TAKE_DATA_Y_BRA ( THIS ) RESULT ( DATA_Y_BR )
!
!    IMPLICIT NONE
!
!    CLASS ( TS_SHIR ) :: THIS
!    COMPLEX :: DATA_Y_BR
!
!    DATA_Y_BR = THIS%Y_BRA
!
!RETURN
!END FUNCTION TAKE_DATA_Y_BRA

END MODULE CLASS_BRANCHES

PROGRAM TYPE_ALLOCATABLE_ARRAY

USE , NON_INTRINSIC :: CLASS_BRANCHES

IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER :: I , J
INTEGER , PARAMETER :: N_BRANCHES = 5 , N_CALCULATIONS = 6
CHARACTER( 250 ) , DIMENSION ( N_CALCULATIONS ) :: UN_NAME
CHARACTER(*) , PARAMETER :: UN_FMT = '("OUTPUT_",I2.2,".TXT")'  

CLASS ( TS_SHIR ) , POINTER :: P_BRA
TYPE ( TS_SHIR ) , DIMENSION ( N_CALCULATIONS ) , TARGET :: BRANCHES  

LOOP_00: DO I = 1 , N_CALCULATIONS

            P_BRA => BRANCHES(I)

            CALL P_BRA%CALCULATION_TS_SHIR( N_BRANCHES )

            WRITE( UN_NAME(I) , UN_FMT ) I

            OPEN ( 15 , FILE = UN_NAME(I) , STATUS = 'UNKNOWN' , ACTION = 'WRITE' )

              DO J = 1 , N_BRANCHES

                 WRITE( 15 , * ) J ! HOW TO WRITE VALUES OF Y_GRA( N_BRA ) WITH MEMBER FUNCTION OF TYPE TS_SHIR???

              END DO

            CLOSE ( 15 , STATUS = 'KEEP')

         END DO LOOP_00

END PROGRAM TYPE_ALLOCATABLE_ARRAY
```

I am very new in object oriented programing in Fortran so I need an explanation about taking values of `Type`private member ( allocatable array ) by public procedure `TAKE_Y_BRA`. I put under comment the body of function `TAKE_Y_BRA` because I got his message:
`Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment` at line where is this command:
`DATA_Y_BR = THIS%Y_BRA`
Is there any solution for this or I have a totally wrong approach for this kind of calculation with derived types?

Comment: @VladimirF Module are in separate file.

Comment: You must tell us what is the puropse of `TAKE_DATA_Y_BRA`. I do not understand it. Which value should it return? Which element of the array? Or the full array?

Comment: The error message (correctly) refers to where you are trying to assign an array to a scalar.  I also can't see what you are wanting to do, so can't tell you how to fix this, just that you need to fix it.

Comment: @VladimirF In the body of function `TAKE_DATA_Y_BRA` the type of returning values is complex. In main program, I want to write element of array `Y_BRA` just afther `J` in same row of course.

Comment: But which element? The whole array, or the first value or which one? There are `N` elements in the array. You are returning just one number.

Comment: @VladimirF Element which corresponding with `J => Y_BRA (J)`.

Comment: @VladimirF I this way of programing good for this kind of calculation or there is some other, more efficient, way with using procedures?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Which way of programming?

Comment: @VladimirF Using object oriented programming in this way, like in my example?

Comment: It is just a different style. It can help the organization of large programs but one must be used to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either return the whole array

```
FUNCTION TAKE_DATA_Y_BRA ( THIS ) RESULT ( DATA_Y_BR )
   CLASS ( TS_SHIR ) :: THIS
   COMPLEX :: DATA_Y_BR(SIZE(THIS%Y_BRA))

   DATA_Y_BR = THIS%Y_BRA
END FUNCTION TAKE_DATA_Y_BRA
```

Or return one element at index `J`

```
FUNCTION TAKE_DATA_Y_BRA_J ( THIS, J ) RESULT ( DATA_Y_BR )
   CLASS ( TS_SHIR ) :: THIS
   INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: J
   COMPLEX :: DATA_Y_BR

   DATA_Y_BR = THIS%Y_BRA(J)
END FUNCTION TAKE_DATA_Y_BRA_J
```

Note you don't really need the `implicit none` and `return`. Be concise. Your code is hard to read! Use small caps for better readability.